# Invalid Dates Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python. I was just wondering, how can you write code that makes beyond a certain date an invalid input. For example, if the user inputs anything after 12/02/2013, it will produce an error. Everything after that date will work perfectly

Comment: How exactly are your dates defined? Strings? `datetime` objects? What sort of error are you looking for? A printed message? An exception? Have you made any attempts to solve this on your own? If so, can you show what you tried and describe how it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

As glibdud suggested, use *datetime* objects.

```
date = datetime.date(YYYY, MM, DD)
```

where (YYYY, MM, DD) are integers representing years, months, and days. The condition can then be checked in your script with

```
inputDate > maxDate
```

for example:

```
import datetime 

maxDate = datetime.date(2013, 12, 2)

y = int(input('Enter year:'))    
m = int(input('Enter numerical month (1-12):'))    
d = int(input('Enter numerical day (1-31):'))

inputDate = datetime.date(y, m, d)

if inputDate > maxDate:
    print('Error - date after 02 December 2013')    
else:
    print('Success!')
```

Gives:

> Enter year:2018
>
> Enter numerical month (1-12):1
>
> Enter numerical day (1-31):1
>
> Error - date after 02 December 2013

and

> Enter year:2000
>
> Enter numerical month (1-12):1
>
> Enter numerical day (1-31):1
>
> Success!